# Cannot install jupyter notebook using pip3

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install jupyter notebook using pip3, but I received the following errors. May I know how to resolve this? Many thanks!!

```
Failed building wheel for pyrsistent

Running setup.py clean for pyrsistent

Failed to build pyrsistent

Installing collected packages: pyrsistent, jsonschema, nbformat, entrypoints, nbconvert, notebook, widgetsnbextension, ipywidgets, jupyter
  Running setup.py install for pyrsistent ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\esthe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fzxj8the\\pyrsistent\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\esthe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rjbq8ckm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    copying _pyrsistent_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\typing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_checked_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_field_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_immutable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_pbag.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_pclass.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_pdeque.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_plist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_pmap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_precord.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_pset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_pvector.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_toolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\_transformations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    copying pyrsistent\typing.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\pyrsistent
    running build_ext
    building 'pvectorc' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\esthe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fzxj8the\\pyrsistent\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\esthe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rjbq8ckm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\esthe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fzxj8the\pyrsistent\
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using to install jupyter notebook using pip. Also, this website might help. https://jupyter.org/install

Comment: maybe you should try to install with admin access?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today with python35. 
I fixed it with python36. Just install python 3.6 run 'pip install jupyter' in cmd.